# Silex - How to access my web root and application root

Tags: php, twig, silex

Are there are functions I can call via my $app variable (Silex\Application) to get access to the web root and application root?

Assuming my project layout is like this

```
/src    <-- Contains bootstrap.php (register all required services), controllers.php (routes)
/vendor <-- Contains autoload.php and Silex source
/web    <-- Contains index.php, Creates $app, includes app/bootstrap.php and $app->run()
```

And in src/controllers.php I might want to reference my doc root or app root

```
$app
    ->get('/', function () use ($app) {
        // Would like to do something like
        $webRoot = $app->getWebRoot();

        return $app['twig']->render('home.html.twig');
    })
    ->bind('home');
```

I have found something I can use in Twig templates but no convenience method in PHP

```
<link href="{{ app.request.baseUrl }}/libs/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I can use __DIR__, dirname(), etc but was curious if there was another way

Comment: I have a 'bootstrap' script that loads a class that has all the 'configuration directories' as properties and 'members'. This runs before 'silex' so is available 'everywhere'. You could easily add it to 'silex'. It also has the 'runtime_environment' of 'dev', 'test' etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twig's `app.request.baseurl` is available in php as `$app["request"]->getBaseUrl()` or `$request->getBaseUrl()` if you have the request injected into your controller.

As for the app root, I've always done `define("ROOT", __DIR__ . "/../")` in my bootstrap file.

Comment: Not sure why but getBaseUrl and getBasePath both return empty strings. However the other methods on the Request object seem to work ok, e.g. getPathInfo and getRequestUri.

Comment: The root solution seems nice by the way :D

Comment: This answers my original question, now to find why "getBaseUrl" and "getBasePath" are returning empty strings

Comment: @Carlton, it's possible that you're getting empty strings from `getBasePath`/`getBaseUrl` if you call them too early -- I can't find any specific documentation on it, but it seems that you have to wait until after `$app->run()` is called (in other words, it will work from within a route handler, but not just at the top-level of your code).